# Roblox remove mesh from game

Tags: lua, roblox

When I equip my pet I use this code (and it works fine):

```
local humanoidRootPart = character:WaitForChild('HumanoidRootPart')
local backpackItem = game.ReplicatedStorage.Meshes[pet.Name]:Clone()  
backpackItem.Parent = game.Workspace

RunService.Stepped:Connect(function()
    local location = humanoidRootPart.CFrame
    backpackItem.CFrame = location * CFrame.new(2, 2, 3)
end)
```

This will add a mesh(pet) over the player shoulder. But if I add a new mesh this will go inside the other mesh. How can I remove the current mesh from the game? If I destroy all the meshes in the mesh folder they still show in the game.

```
for i,v in pairs(collectionInventory:GetChildren()) do
    v:Destroy()
end
```

So anyone know how I can remove the current mesh hovering over the players shoulder before I add the new mesh?

Thanks!

Comment: Typically, setting the Parent property of the mesh to nil is enough to remove something from the world. Calling Destroy does that too. If you print out the contents of the collectionInventory, do you see all of the pets you expect? You've set the Parent of each of the meshes to the Workspace, are you sure that the collection inventory is correctly referring to the meshes you want to remove?

Comment: @Kylaaa: Thank you! That pointed me in the right direction. Created a folder in the workspace where I keep the items and which I clean up before I add a new one.